# Issue running Golang server binary as a service with Systemd

Tags: systemd, service, centos8, go

I am trying to run a Golang server binary as a service with **Systemd** on **Centos 8**, but I get an error.

This is my script `/etc/systemd/system/myserverapp.service`

```
[Unit]
Description=MyServerApp

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/var/mybin/myserverapp

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This is what I type:

```
sudo systemctl enable myserverapp
sudo systemctl start myserverapp
```

but it doesn't start, and if I type:

```
sudo systemctl status myserverapp
```

this is what I get:

```
● myserverapp.service - MyServerApp
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myserverapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-04-20 19:36:36 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 11228 ExecStart=/var/mybin/myserverapp (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: 11228 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: myserverapp.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: myserverapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: myserverapp.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: myserverapp.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: Stopped MyServerApp.
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: myserverapp.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: myserverapp.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 20 19:36:36 myserver systemd[1]: Failed to start MyServerApp.
```

notice that if I run:
`sudo /var/mybin/myserverapp` from the shell, the server binary runs correctly

Answer (score 4):

I found the problem!

It was due to the **SELinux policy**, which was denying **Systemd** to run my server app as a service, as it was in a non-standard bin directory `/var/mybin/`.

you can verify the SELinux denied executions by running the command:

```
sudo ausearch -m avc -ts today
```

There are 2 possible solutions:

1) move the binary to a standard bin directory like `/usr/local/bin`

2) add a `bin_t` SELinux rule to the `/var/mybin/myserverapp` file, so that Systemd can run it as a service.

To apply solution 2), you just need to run the command:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t bin_t /var/mybin/myserverapp
```

if you want to list all current SELinux rules, just type:

```
sudo semanage fcontext -l
```

in case `semanage` is not installed on your system, you can simply install it with this command:

```
sudo dnf install policycoreutils-python-utils
```